# Need 10 reputation to upvote comments, but this isn't documented

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

You need 10 reputation to upvote comments, but this isn't documented on the team's privileges page (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/c/teamname/help/privileges?tab=all).

That should be added to the list of privileges.

Comment: Isn't this the same for [so]?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not, but the upvote button is not displayed. Probably you can with some javascript hack?

Comment: thanks for reporting this. this is unintentional and we're working on fixing this.

Comment: @user202729 It's not indicated on Stack Overflow's privilege page, either. You need 15 reputation to upvote questions and answers but no such requirement is listed for comments.

Comment: I see that you are looking at `team` documentation. This _is_ documented for individuals at [https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @G5W I don’t see it at the link you’ve provided either.

Comment: Odd.  Works for me.  How about by navigation?  Please click the ? at top right. It will offer a menu, select "Help Center".  On the Help Center page, I see only one entry under "Privileges"  It says "View a full list of privileges you can earn" and goes to the same page.

Comment: Hmm.  If I click the page mentioned in the original question, I get "Page not Found". It seems like individual users do not see the team pages and teams do not see the individual pages.

Comment: @G5W I don't see it at the normal page either. There is voting at 15 reputation, but this seems to be part of "remove new user restrictions" which doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: @ChanceHeath this seems fixed. Can you add in an answer and mark as [status-completed]? :)